# Magento 2 {{store url="tipps"}} trailing slash and redirect

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

If I add a link in WYSIWYG-Editor like `{{store url="tipps"}}`. Magento 2 makes link to `http://www.domain.at/tipps/`. But, after clicking on the link `http://www.domain.at/tipps/` Magento is redirecting to  `http://www.domain.at/tipps` (without the slash).

How can I configure Magento 2 to make the correct link http://www.domain.at/tipps instead of http://www.domain.at/tipps/?

Comment: still you facing issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you need to use store direct_url for that.

e.g

```
<a href="{{store direct_url='tipps'}}">Test</a>
```